# Difference between disabled class of bootstrap and disabled attribute

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi friends i am using disabled class as well as disabled attribute as follows however i dont know the basic difference between both and when we have to use class and when to use attribute please clear my doubt
    I am using button  in my code and i want to disable it so what will be the best way either use class disabled or attribute disabled

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary disabled" type=" button"/>
    disabled="disabled"
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you look at the bootstrap definitions the disabled styles are always defined for the presence of the disabled class or the disabled attributed:

```
.btn.disabled,
.btn[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    ...
}
```

So for styling you only need either class or the attribute.

Previous versions also included `pointer-events: none;` which disabled mouse clicks on the button. Here setting either the disabled class or attribute effectively disabled the button.

In the current version 3.3.5 the `pointer-events: none;` was dropped from `.btn`. Then if you only use the class, the button looks disabled but still can be clicked.

Therefore I would use the disabled attribute for buttons.

Comment: i read somewhere that if we want to disable button then use attribute disabled and for links use class disabled is it right to follow?

Comment: correct since `<a>` does not have a disabled attribute.

Comment: this is the only difference or anything else remaining there?